# get src attribute inside div tag jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse the html but getting nullpointor. I want to extract image uri from the below html.

```
String html = "<div class=\"thumb-box thumb-160\"><a class=\"mimg\" data-id=\"1394085169856_6744\" href=\"#\"><img class=\"thumb\" src=\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/u7deClndzQw/hqdefault.jpg\" style=\"top: -15px;\"><span class=\"btn\"></span></a></div>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element element = document.select("div.thumb-box thumb-160").first();

System.out.println(element.select("img").attr("src"));
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: How to extract image uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element element = document.select("div.thumb-box thumb-160").first();
```

you have to use `.` (dot) for every class

```
Element element = document.select("div.thumb-box.thumb-160").first();
```

Besides it is rather straight forward do select like this

```
Element element = document.select("div.thumb-box.thumb-160:eq(0) a").first();
```

This yould yet you anchor element out of the box

Comment: I think `div.thumb-box thumb-160` is one class.

Comment: you think wrong. class=`a b` in CSS means both classes a and b

Comment: Accept answer that and we are even :)

Comment: Definitely I'll after 8 minutes :D because I can't right now.